# Are there any online resources for finding all public officers for a given zip code in the United States?

Tags: united-states, local-government, reference-request

Looking for something akin to CallMyCongress dot com, but for local public officials.  The best I can find so far through research is that some town/municipality websites are very helpful, in that some have comprehensive lists of public officials for their locale, but I have yet to find a national online service.  I am particularly interested in identifying local law enforcement officials by zip.

Any recommendations are very much appreciated, thank you for your time.

Comment: So far as I know, no such service exists. There used to be government pages in phone books back in the days when people used phone books, that would have provided this information for people in the phone book service area. But, nobody uses phone books that way any more. Also, ZIP codes are too small. Most local officials serve many ZIP codes and many ZIP codes are served by multiple local officials as elected official districts rarely follow ZIP code boundaries.

Comment: When you say "law enforcement officials", could you be more specific? Do you mean the Attorney General's office? The police chief?

Comment: Appreciate the feedback about ZIP's.

BarryCarter:  Yes, and yes.  Ideally all elected positions by address

Answer (score 1):

One project I'm aware of is the '[MyReps](https://myreps.datamade.us/)' tool, which was created by DataMade & the Participatory Budgeting Project. This uses Google's [Civic Information API](https://developers.google.com/civic-information/) to provide a nice interface which allows you to type in your zip code and receive a list of elected representatives.  From DataMade's [announcement blog post](https://datamade.us/blog/we-find-your-reps-so-you-dont-have-to/):

> In every city, town, and county road in America, you are represented
> by people voted into office. Some of these people you know: the
> president, your town’s mayor, and perhaps the governor of your state.
>
> But what about the rest? Do you know who your 2 Senators are? Or how
> about your member from the House of Representatives? Or your city
> council members? Your county government? The board of your Mosquito
> Abatement District? (Yes, this is a real thing.)
>
> Chances are you don’t know them all, or even the majority of them. But
> these people still represent you and make important decisions on your
> behalf.

The project is open-source and can be viewed on [GitHub](https://github.com/datamade/my-reps).